# Issue with file_get_contents when count is more then 1

Tags: php, file-get-contents

All,
I have the following code:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'timeout' => 5      // Timeout in seconds
    )
));
$username = $options['account'];
$contents = file_get_contents( "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name={$username}&count=1", 0, $context );
```

When I execute this code it works fine. However when I change the contents to this:

```
$how_many = $options['how_many'];
$contents = file_get_contents( "    
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name={$username}&count={$how_many}", 0, $context );
```

I get the following error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=Username&count=10) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No error

Any ideas why it would work for one and not for the other. If I copy and paste that URL into a browser results are returned as well.

Comment: Check to see if $context is actually there, either that or you missed to put it on your post.

Comment: you misspelled `$how_many` in the first line of your second sample.

Comment: You're sure it's nothing to do with `$how_man` not being the same as `$how_many`?

Comment: It is a typo. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using cURL to get all of the values and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

shouldnt

how_many be $how_man? or is it a typo?

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name={$username}&count={$how_man}", 0, $context );
```